# how to construct string using surrogate pairs

Tags: java, unicode

I am trying to construct a char by using codepoints within either high-surrogates range, (\uD800-\uDBFF) or low-surrogate range, according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html
the code sample is

```
      for (int cp = Character.MIN_SURROGATE; cp <= Character.MAX_SURROGATE; cp++) {
            char c = (char) cp;
            if (Character.isHighSurrogate(c)) {
                char low = Character.lowSurrogate(cp);
                System.out.println(Character.isSurrogatePair(c, low));
            } else if (Character.isLowSurrogate(c)) {
                char high = Character.highSurrogate(cp);
                System.out.println(Character.isSurrogatePair(high, c));
            }
        }
```

What confuses me is that all high-surrogate char can find the corresponding low surrogate pair by calling`Character.lowSurrogate` and `Character.isSurrogatePair(c, low)` is always true but the low-surrogate char can not find corresponding high surrogate pair and `Character.highSurrogat` always return the same char with code point `55287`.

Any idea how to construct a valid character given a low surrogate char?

Answer (score 1):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of what surrogates are and how they work together.  I suggest you read up on [how UTF-16 actually works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

`Character.is(High|Low)Surrogate()` take a **UTF-16 codeunit** as input.  If the result is `true`, calling `Character.(high|low)Surrogate()` on the *same numeric value* doesn't do what you think it does.  You can't *find* a low surrogate from a high surrogate, and vice versa.  Any high surrogate can be combined with many different low surrogates (ie, `D800 DC00`, `D800 DC01`, `D800 DC02`, ...), and vice versa any low surrogate can be combined with many different high surrogates (ie, `D800 DC00`, `D801 DC00`, `D802 DC00`, ...), to produce different Unicode codepoints.

`Character.(high|low)Surrogate()` take a **Unicode codepoint** as input and return the high/low surrogates needed to encode that codepoint in UTF-16, respectively.

You are enumerating **codeunits** and treating them *as-if* they were **codepoints**, which they are not (**codepoints** in the range of **UTF-16 surrogates** are reserved and thus invalid for use in any context).  IOW, you are mixing apples and tangerines, so of course the results are not what you are expecting.

Let's take a deeper look at your code example in context.  Let's look at the two extremes that your loop processes, `Character.MIN_SURROGATE` (`'\uD800'`) and `Character.MAX_SURROGATE` (`'\uDFFF'`). The same will be true for all other values in between:

- `isHighSurrogate((char)0xD800)` returns `true` and `Character.isLowSurrogate((char)0xD800)` returns `false`, because **codeunit** `D800` is in the range of *high* surrogate codeunits (`D800..DBFF`).
- `isHighSurrogate((char)0xDFFF)` returns `false` and `Character.isLowSurrogate((char)0xDFFF)` returns `true`, because **codeunit** `DFFF` is in the range of *low* surrogate codeunits (`DC00..DFFF`).
- `Character.lowSurrogate((int)0xD800)` and `Character.highSurrogate((int)0xDFFF)` both return an **unspecified** `char` value, because `0xD800` and `0xDFFF` are not valid "supplementary characters" (Unicode codepoints) in the range of `Character.MIN_SUPPLEMENTARY_CODE_POINT..Character.MAX_CODE_POINT` (`U+10000..U+10FFFF`), ie `Character.isSupplementaryCodePoint()` returns `false`.  Per Java's documentation:

[`lowSurrogate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#lowSurrogate-int-)

> Returns the trailing surrogate (a **low surrogate code unit**) of the surrogate pair representing the specified supplementary character (**Unicode code point**) in the UTF-16 encoding. **If the specified character is not a supplementary character, an unspecified `char` is returned.**

[`highSurrogate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#highSurrogate-int-)

> Returns the leading surrogate (a **high surrogate code unit**) of the surrogate pair representing the specified supplementary character (**Unicode code point**) in the UTF-16 encoding. **If the specified character is not a supplementary character, an unspecified `char` is returned.**

[`isSupplementaryCodePoint()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSupplementaryCodePoint-int-)

> Determines whether the specified character (**Unicode code point**) is in the supplementary character range.
>
> ...
>
> Returns:
> true if the specified code point is between `MIN_SUPPLEMENTARY_CODE_POINT` and `MAX_CODE_POINT` inclusive; false otherwise.

So, generally speaking, if `Character.isHighSurrogate()` returns `true`, `Character.lowSurrogate()` for the *same numeric value* is **undefined**.  And if `Character.isLowSurrogate()` returns `true`, `Character.highSurrogate()` for the *same numeric value* is **undefined**.

Thus, your claims that "*all high-surrogate char can find the corresponding low surrogate pair by calling `Character.lowSurrogate`*" and "*`Character.isSurrogatePair(c, low)` is always true*" are both wrong.

And your claim that "*the low-surrogate char can not find corresponding high surrogate pair*" is correct, but your claim that "*`Character.highSurrogate` always return the same char with code point 55287*" is wrong.

Lastly, regarding your actual question:

> Any idea how to construct a valid character given a low surrogate char?

You can't construct a Unicode codepoint from just a high or low surrogate alone.  It is the *combination* of high+low surrogates *acting together* that defines a specific codepoint.  You need both surrogates.  If you only have 1 surrogate, then you don't have enough bits to re-construct the codepoint. Period.